# How to refactorice properties using json schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'd like to reference and factor the following json schema in multiple files for a better handling regarding its properties. Files as "$ref": "book.json" and "$ref": "pencil.json" which each file has its own properties and validations (and of course, that it works "addProperties = false"), I have the following schema:

```
{
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string" 
    },

    "type": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["Pencil", "Book"]
    },
      
    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    },

    "content": {
      "type": "string"
    },

    "domain": {
      "type": "string"
    },

    "img_url": {
      "type": "string"
    },

    "url": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },

  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "enum": ["Book"]
          }
        }
      },
      
      "then": {
        "required": [
          "domain", "img_url", "url"
        ],

        "not" : {
          "anyOf" : [
            { "required" : ["content"] }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    
    {  
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "enum": ["Pencil"]
          }
        }
      },

      "then": {
        "required": [
          "content"
        ],

        "not" : {
          "anyOf" : [
            { "required" : ["domain"] },
            { "required" : ["img_url"] },
            { "required" : ["url"] }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
 
}
```

**and I would like something like this:**

```
# book.json
{
  "properties": {
    "content": {
      "type": "string"
      
    }
  },

  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "type": {
        "enum": ["Book"]
      }
    }
  },

  "then": {
    "required": [
      "content"
    ],

    "not" : {
      "anyOf" : [
        { "required" : ["domain"] },
        { "required" : ["img_url"] },
        { "required" : ["url"] }
      ]
    }
  }
}
   
# pencil.json 
{ 
  "properties":{
    "domain": {
      "type": "string"
    },

    "img_url": {
      "type": "string"
    },

    "url": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },

  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "type": {
        "enum": ["Pencil"]
      }
    }
  },
  
  "then": {
    "required": [
      "domain", "img_url", "url"
    ],

    "not" : {
      "anyOf" : [
        { "required" : ["content"] }
      ]
    }
  }
}

# properties.json

 {
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "$ref": book.json,
    "$ref": pencil.json 
  }
```

I would like to simplify it, whether a property is of the book or pencil type then it refers to the file where this file has its properties and validations.

Comment: Do you want to break up your schema into multiple schemas because you have many possible conditions?

Comment: Exactly, because each condition has its own properties and it grows.

I would like to divide them into several parts, for each property a different file, the book.json has its own properties and validations, just like the pencil.json and finally a file called properties.json which is the one that will contain all its references

(1) all properties are on the same level

(2) and that {"addProperties" = false}, works for me


Is what I'm stuck

Comment: While I don't have time today to fully form you an answer here, you may find this article on JSON Schema bundling provides an example of how files can be separated using `$ref` and `$id`: https://json-schema.org/blog/posts/bundling-json-schema-compound-documents
I also recomend reading about structuring in our learning resources https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html